# vue axios returns Unexpected console statement when I try to console log

Tags: vue.js, axios

I'm trying to `console.log` **jsonplaceholder** posts with `axios` using `vue`, but it returns unexpected console statement and points to the `console.log`.

Here is the code:

```js
<script>
import axios from 'axios';
export default {
  name: 'app',
  data(){
      return {
        blog:{
          categories:[]
        }
      }
  },
  mounted: function() {
    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
      .then(response => console.log(response));
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: could you show us the error please

Comment: Are you referring to ESLint `no-console` rule? https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-console

Answer (score 0):

use

```
.then(response => window.console.log(response));
```

Comment: While this might answer the question, a bit of explanation would be extremely helpful, click edit and please type in some explanation.